# $f(x) = x^4 − 32x^2 + 1$ Find the local minimum and maximum, inflection points, and concavity.

Tags: calculus

So I already did this problem. Here is my answer. I am not sure if I made basic math error or the program will only take values typed a certain way. Also I checked the graph on DESMOS and it gave me the values of $-1$ and $-257$. Helped greatly appreciated. #Enlarge Screen to View#
[image]

Comment: The inflection points are at $x=\pm \sqrt{16/3}$ which can be expressed in various ways, like $\pm 4\sqrt{3}/3$.  I do not know about the preferences of this mechanical grading program. Your max and min are very wrong.

Comment: The local max/min can be obtained from the increasing/decreasing information.

Comment: What so strange. I plugged the numbers into the wrong function.

Answer (score 0):

1)  I'm not sure where you're getting $f(\sqrt{16/3})=2.56$.  That seems to be the main problem.

2) you can simplify $\sqrt{16/3}$, this may or may not be causing a problem

Answer (score 0):

As has already been noted, you should be using exact values for your radicals.

I will also note that it looks like you plotted $x^4+32x -1$ instead of $x^4+32x^2 +1$ when looking for local maxes and mins.